# How much does being at the perihelion heat Earth up?

Tags: orbit, temperature

The author in this article: https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2010/07/100707-aphelion-heat-wave-earth-sun-science-weather-nation/ has explained that positional differences on the orbit is a negligible factor - about 7% more sunlight at the perihelion compared to the aphelion. I suppose the explanation is relatable to people in the Northern/Southern hemispheres, where temperatures are driven by changing seasons.

However, for people in the equator, where daily temperature swings measure only in a matter of few degrees all year round, it would have definitely made some difference. Does anyone know if this temperature change has been investigated before? I would like to read up more about it. Thanks!

Comment: A similar question is answered in some detail here, it addresses insolation (the 7% you mention is part of that), as well as temperature.    https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10037/is-winter-hotter-at-the-equator

Comment: @userLTK Thanks for sharing the link! It has certainly pointed me to the right direction!

Comment: @userLTK good link! However, those answers focus purely on seasonal variation rather than the apsides. The OP's claim that a difference of 7% in insolation is "negligible" is wrong: [apsidal precession contributes to Milankovitch cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles#Apsidal_precession) which have a significant impact on climate **including at the equator**. Perihelion currently in early January contributes to milder northern winters (and harsher southern summers) compared to 12,000 years ago when perihelion was in early July.

Comment: @Chappo - That's a bit orthogonal. I suspect that the OP is asking about now rather than 5000 years from now. Besides, the bellwether latitude regarding Milankovitch cycles is 65°N rather than the equator, and the bellwether month is July rather than January.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes, I was inspired to ask the question as I walked under the hot noon sun to get my lunch earlier. Regardless, I'm still very appreciative of all the thoughts given here as I'm rather new to earth sciences and astronomy, and would like to learn as much as I can :)